# Error thrown Call to undefined function ispage()

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

Some weirdness happening here people. I have just created a custom theme for a new client and any new post that gets published is showing this error. however previous posts are all perfectly fine.

No error log is coming up in the public_html. You can see the error here...
https://www.flairincorporated.com/weddings/chic-weddings/

However all other posts are fine like this one...

https://www.flairincorporated.com/cocktails/lavish-and-luxurious/

I have reuploaded WordPress itself and made sure that all plugins are up to date. Weirdly I disabled guttenberg and there was no difference as well.
Many thanks

Phillip

Comment: ispage -> is_page

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was the Guttenberg update that was causing the issue so I have disabled and deleted it and ammended the post with the classic editor. May need to do further resarch as I have not added that function in my functions.php file or anywhere else.